# How to truncate from rich text?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I want to truncate a text from rich text as below. I tried many things, but they did not work.

```
                    {% for piece in data.pieces %}

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="single-product mb-55 animated fadeInUp" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".1" style="animation-duration: 0.6s; animation-delay: 0.1s;">
                                <span class="tip">{{ piece.title }}</span>
                                <img src="img/products/product1@2x.jpg" data-rjs="2" alt="" data-rjs-processed="true" width="237" height="193">

                                <h3 class="h5">
                                   {{ apos.area(piece, 'body') }}
                                </h3>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- End of Single Product -->
                    {% endfor %}
```

I need to truncate this part. I don't know if there is other way to display the description:

```
{{ apos.area(piece, 'body') }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways you could solve this, you don't provide much in terms of requirements so these would need to finessed to meet your needs.

> Note: Using Nunjuck's `truncate` filter against rich-text (markup)
>   will include all HTML tags and spaces in code against the truncate
>   limit. The examples below use Nunjuck's truncate. This could lead to broken tags in your markup, should a tag be opened, the limit be reached, and then never closed. I would recommend implementing something like [truncate-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truncate-html) as a project-level Nunjucks helper. See [Implementing custom Nunjucks helpers in Apostrophe](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/howtos/migration#adding-nunjucks-helpers-got-easier-and-better)

### Provide area-level truncate settings for your rich-text-widgets

In the schema for your piece, when defining the `body` area, add some flag to your `apostrophe-rich-text` options

```
    {
      name: 'body',
      label: 'Body',
      type: 'area',
      options: {
        widgets: {
          'apostrophe-rich-text': {
            toolbar:[...], // toolbar settings
            styles:[...], // styles settings
            truncate: 250 // truncates after 250 characters
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Then, at a project level override of the `apostrophe-rich-text-widgets` template, watch for those settings to be passed to the rich-text widget. Use Nunjucks built-in `truncate` filter to alter the text content in the widget.

In `lib/modules/apostrophe-rich-text-widgets/views/widget.html`

```
<div data-rich-text class="apos-rich-text">
  {% if data.options.truncate %}
    {{ data.widget.content | safe | truncate(data.options.truncate) }}  
  {% else %}
    {{ data.widget.content | safe }}  
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

**Advantages**: This would work with the setup you've provided above without altering your current data structure of `body`.

**Disadvantages**: This method is brute-force. Your specifying this option at the area level, so all rich-text-widgets within this area will receive the options and they will *all* be truncated accordingly. This same method would work better if you were using a singleton to save your description because you could tightly control where the truncate options happen.

### Wrap your rich-text widgets into new widgets with truncate options

This method involves creating a new widget that contains a rich-text singleton and options for controlling if and how much text to truncate. I'm going to call the widget `truncate-rich-text`

In `lib/modules/truncate-rich-text-widgets/index.js` (create this file and path)

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Truncate Rich Text',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'content',
      label: 'Content',
      type: 'singleton',
      widgetType: 'apostrophe-rich-text',
      options: {
        toolbar:[],
        styles:[]
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'truncate',
      label: 'Truncate this text?',
      type: 'boolean',
      choices: [
        { label: 'Yes', value: true, showFields: ['truncateCharacters'] },
        { label: 'No', value: false }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'truncateCharacters',
      label: 'Character limit',
      type: 'integer'
    }
  ]        
};
```

Then in `lib/modules/truncate-rich-text-widgets/views/widget.html` (create this)

```
<div class="truncate-rich-text">
  {% if data.widget.truncate %}
    {{ data.widget.content.items[0].content | safe | truncate(data.widget.truncateCharacters) }}
  {% else %}
    {{ data.widget.content.items[0].content | safe }}
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Finally, add this new module to your `app.js` configuration.

```
var path = require('path');
var apos = require('apostrophe')({
  shortName: 'myProject',
  modules: {
    // ... other modules
    'truncate-rich-text-widgets': {},
  }
});
```

**Advantages**: This provides more fine-grained control over what text widgets get truncated and can be used more widely across your site.

**Disadvantages**: This would be a new widget in your site configuration, which means you'd have to migrate your content to use it. This also takes a lot of the in-context'ness of editing text in Apostrophe out of the editor user experience, which is a bummer.

Like I said, there are multiple ways to achieve this, and there are also UX subtleties to different situations (maybe you only show truncated text to logged-out users while leaving the full content in for editors because it would be confusing for your text to keep disappearing on save). Hopefully this will open up a few pathways for you to find the right implementation.

Comment: dear stuart , many thanks for your support am new to apostrophe and really it is not easy to understand it , however i follow up with your first solution because what am working at i display for the users news in card design and i want to display only few of the description and in the inner news i will display all ,however  its work like charm many thanks for you, but the thing is i will figuer out how to display all the description inside the inner page lol